# How to get the title of the tuple rather than the tuple value

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, edit, data-mining, apriori

I have title stored for each column  in the csv file and want association rules  between the titles  and this code for apriori algo returns itemsets and their asscociation rules
how can i modify it to get the title(name of the category item belongs to   rather than items itself

```js
"""
Description     : Simple Python implementation of the Apriori Algorithm

Usage:
    $python apriori.py -f DATASET.csv -s minSupport  -c minConfidence

    $python apriori.py -f DATASET.csv -s 0.15 -c 0.6
"""

import sys

from itertools import chain, combinations
from collections import defaultdict
from optparse import OptionParser


def subsets(arr):
    """ Returns non empty subsets of arr"""
    return chain(*[combinations(arr, i + 1) for i, a in enumerate(arr)])


def returnItemsWithMinSupport(itemSet, transactionList, minSupport, freqSet):
        """calculates the support for items in the itemSet and returns a subset
       of the itemSet each of whose elements satisfies the minimum support"""
        _itemSet = set()
        localSet = defaultdict(int)

        for item in itemSet:
                for transaction in transactionList:
                        if item.issubset(transaction):
                                freqSet[item] += 1
                                localSet[item] += 1

        for item, count in localSet.items():
                support = float(count)/len(transactionList)

                if support >= minSupport:
                        _itemSet.add(item)

        return _itemSet


def joinSet(itemSet, length):
        """Join a set with itself and returns the n-element itemsets"""
        return set([i.union(j) for i in itemSet for j in itemSet if len(i.union(j)) == length])


def getItemSetTransactionList(data_iterator):
    transactionList = list()
    itemSet = set()
    for record in data_iterator:
        transaction = frozenset(record)
        transactionList.append(transaction)
        for item in transaction:
            itemSet.add(frozenset([item]))              # Generate 1-itemSets
    return itemSet, transactionList


def runApriori(data_iter, minSupport, minConfidence):
    """
    run the apriori algorithm. data_iter is a record iterator
    Return both:
     - items (tuple, support)
     - rules ((pretuple, posttuple), confidence)
    """
    itemSet, transactionList = getItemSetTransactionList(data_iter)

    freqSet = defaultdict(int)
    largeSet = dict()
    # Global dictionary which stores (key=n-itemSets,value=support)
    # which satisfy minSupport

    assocRules = dict()
    # Dictionary which stores Association Rules

    oneCSet = returnItemsWithMinSupport(itemSet,
                                        transactionList,
                                        minSupport,
                                        freqSet)

    currentLSet = oneCSet
    k = 2
    while(currentLSet != set([])):
        largeSet[k-1] = currentLSet
        currentLSet = joinSet(currentLSet, k)
        currentCSet = returnItemsWithMinSupport(currentLSet,
                                                transactionList,
                                                minSupport,
                                                freqSet)
        currentLSet = currentCSet
        k = k + 1

    def getSupport(item):
            """local function which Returns the support of an item"""
            return float(freqSet[item])/len(transactionList)

    toRetItems = []
    for key, value in largeSet.items():
        toRetItems.extend([(tuple(item), getSupport(item))
                           for item in value])

    toRetRules = []
    for key, value in largeSet.items()[1:]:
        for item in value:
            _subsets = map(frozenset, [x for x in subsets(item)])
            for element in _subsets:
                remain = item.difference(element)
                if len(remain) > 0:
                    confidence = getSupport(item)/getSupport(element)
                    if confidence >= minConfidence:
                        toRetRules.append(((tuple(element), tuple(remain)),
                                           confidence))
    return toRetItems, toRetRules


def printResults(items, rules):
    """prints the generated itemsets sorted by support and the confidence rules sorted by confidence"""
    for item, support in sorted(items, key=lambda (item, support): support):
        print "item: %s , %.3f" % (str(item), support)
    print "\n------------------------ RULES:"
    for rule, confidence in sorted(rules, key=lambda (rule, confidence): confidence):
        pre, post = rule
        print "Rule: %s ==> %s , %.3f" % (str(pre), str(post), confidence)


def dataFromFile(fname):
        """Function which reads from the file and yields a generator"""
        file_iter = open(fname, 'rU')
        for line in file_iter:
                line = line.strip().rstrip(',')                         # Remove trailing comma
                record = frozenset(line.split(','))
                yield record


if __name__ == "__main__":

    optparser = OptionParser()
    optparser.add_option('-f', '--inputFile',
                         dest='input',
                         help='filename containing csv',
                         default=None)
    optparser.add_option('-s', '--minSupport',
                         dest='minS',
                         help='minimum support value',
                         default=0.15,
                         type='float')
    optparser.add_option('-c', '--minConfidence',
                         dest='minC',
                         help='minimum confidence value',
                         default=0.6,
                         type='float')

    (options, args) = optparser.parse_args()

    inFile = None
    if options.input is None:
            inFile = sys.stdin
    elif options.input is not None:
            inFile = dataFromFile(options.input)
    else:
            print 'No dataset filename specified, system with exit\n'
            sys.exit('System will exit')

    minSupport = options.minS
    minConfidence = options.minC

    items, rules = runApriori(inFile, minSupport, minConfidence)

    printResults(items, rules)
```

Comment: What is the "title of the tuple"? A tuple is this: `(1,2)` - what is the title?

Comment: Suppose i have a table in cvs the 1st row contains the attribute names.I want to extract those attribute names.Pardon my poor english

Answer (score 0):

If the first row in the csv contains the names of each column, you can do this:

```
import csv
with open('C:/mypath/to/csvfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    d_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    headers = d_reader.fieldnames
```